# RSelenium & Web Scraping

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape data but I'm having trouble scraping it. I'm able to navigate through website using RSelenium. You can find my code below. I want to scrape names from each drop down so that I can store them in an object and run a loop.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

rd<-rsDriver()
remDr<-rd[["client"]]

url<-"https://kvk.icar.gov.in/facilities_list.aspx"

jsScript <- "var element = arguments[0]; return element.outerHTML;"

webpage<-read_html(url)

remDr$navigate("https://kvk.icar.gov.in/facilities_list.aspx")

remDr$refresh()

#First drop down

stateEle<-remDr$findElement("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState")
#webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict")
stateHTML <- remDr$executeScript(jsScript, list(stateEle))[[1]]
statedoc <- htmlParse(appHTML)
states<-doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "name")]
stateEle$clickElement()
stateEle$sendKeysToElement(states[[30]])
stateEle$clickElement()

#Second drop down

distEle<-remDr$findElement("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict")
distHTML <- remDr$executeScript(jsScript, list(distEle))[[1]]
distdoc <- htmlParse(appHTML)
districts<-doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]
distEle$clickElement()
distEle$sendKeysToElement(list(distdoc[[2]]))
distEle$clickElement()

#Third drop down

kvkEle<-remDr$findElement("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlKvk")
appHTML <- remDr$executeScript(jsScript, list(kvkEle))[[1]]
kvkdoc <- htmlParse(appHTML)
kvk<-doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]
kvkEle$clickElement()
kvkEle$sendKeysToElement(list(kvk[[2]]))
kvkEle$clickElement()

#submitting the values

submitEle<-remDr$findElement("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit")
submitEle$clickElement()
```

Also I want to scrape the results into a dataframe.

Comment: You could try just clicking on the select list, without ``value = `` part, and sending the first few keys of your value (say ``ANDAMAN``). Note that the value you want should be highlighted, then send ``Enter`` key. For this you will want to read about ``sendKey`` functionality of Selenium.

Comment: I tried using this. Now i want to store the names from drop downs so that I can run a loop.

Comment: Checkout my answer and please accept it if does what you're looking for to close the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code,

```
stateEle<-remDr$findElement("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState")
```

From here, if you want to get all values to do the looping, use:

```
library(magrittr)
stateEle$getElementText()[[1]] %>% strsplit(., '\\n')
```

This will provide a list of text elements, where you could further remove the `"--Select--"` option:

```
stateEle$getElementText()[[1]] %>% strsplit(., '\\n') %>% unlist %>% setdiff(., '--Select--')
```

Repeat this for all other select lists.

Comment: So I am able to loop through all the the drop downs. But in the end I am having problem in scraping the data after a page opens. @Nutle

Comment: @ParitoshSharma what was the problem? I suggest you open another question describing what didn't work for you and what was your expected outcome.

Comment: You can see my new question and the problem that I am facing. @Nutle